# Flutter FCM topic messages from multiple firebase projects

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way in Flutter to receive topic notifications from multiple firebase projects, i have been looking for a way but no luck, Flutter plugin do not seem to have even the generated token by sender id method, i am also looking for a way to implement it using rest api but have no idea where to start.any directions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Functions should help you out here.  Cloud Functions allow you to perform database, auth, cloud messaging and other functions on the server side.  You can crate a web app on fiebase console and call the functions using https.  Here is link to a tutorial I found very useful:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9i_aLkr62adUTJi53y7OjOf

Comment: this was the first think i found, however, there are upcoming restrictions on Firebase Cloud Functions, i think it will soon be paid service not sure, what was confusing is that you have to initialize a second app with a senderId i thought that you receive senderId alogside any messages and then separate witch message comes from witch project.

Comment: As far as the paid service required, it still has a minimum free section.  I still have had zero dev costs, since switching to the blaze plan.  The message sending can be done by topic, the device subscribes to the topic, then wherever it is sent from, you can send a unique sender ID inside the data section of the message.  The data section is just a list of maps that you can filter through.

Comment: I will try this and come back

Comment: So actually there is not support for multiple apps in the firebase messaging pluging, there is no instanceFor(FirebaseApp app), and stated in the documentation [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/core/usage#secondary-firebase-apps)

Comment: You can initialize a secondary app in the function and send the through there.  I'll see if I can create an example and edit my answer.

Comment: i looked up in the admin sdk and can not find getToken(senderId, scope), app must register the client app with the second firebase app and get its unique token that should be able to receive messages from that app, when receiving one can check senderId and know which one sent the message, i am also looking up an http endpoint that returns a token given a senderId and "FCM" scope but no luck so far, i even think about creating a plugin to firebase instance id but as a beginner it's hard.

Comment: You might be able to create an api through JS and jwt and host it through firebase.  Then, you can send it through the message.  You can, also, store a senderId in the custom claims section of firebase Auth.  Net Ninja has a good tutorial on that too.

Comment: i can actually receive notifications from both firebase projects, when sent from the console, a senderId is added to the payload , the missing part in the hole thing is that a client app must have a registration token for the default app and another one for the second app, when sending add senderId in the payload, when receiving check witch senderId sent the message, however, the plugin is not exposing the method getToken(senderId, scope), that would solve it, because then there is an instanceId http api that let you subscribe a registration token to a topic.

Answer (score 0):

Its true, the firebase dependence to flutter don't have support to this functionality, but you can create methodChannel to call native code from flutter

**First, add MethodChannel in anywhere**

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('flutter.native/helper'); //<-- This string argument is custom, but must the same in java code
Future<void> responseFromNativeCode() async {
  String response = "";
  try {
    String senderID = '52723600452'; // <----- this is the identifier of another project
    final String result = await platform.invokeMethod(
      'onNewToken', <String, dynamic>{'senderId': senderID});
    response = result;
    print(response); // <----- this is the token, with this, you can receive notifications from another firebase project
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    response = "Failed to Invoke: '${e.message}'.";
    print(response);
  }
}
```

This solution only works in android, but, you need implements to ios too... swift

**Now... you need implement the methodChannel in android and add firebase implementation... here is a example**

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private String CHANNEL = "flutter.native/helper";//This string must be same in flutter declaration
  private String token = "";

  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);

    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
                    if(call.method.equals("onNewToken")){//This string must be same too in flutter declaration
                        String senderId = call.argument("senderId");
                        TokenOtherProject a = new TokenOtherProject();
                        AsyncTask b = a.execute(senderId);
                        try {
                            b.get();//This is like await in flutter
                            result.success(token);//with this, you send the token to flutter project... and handler in page or idk
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
}

private class TokenOtherProject extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(params[0],
                    FirebaseMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("*TokenNuevo: " , token + " ");
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}}
```

You can get more information to how you can communicate with native...
flutter fcm package must have this functionality but no :/

Anyway ... good luck